# Limit on the number of Virtual Web Servers on Mac OS X Sever V10.6.8?

Tags: apache-http-server, virtual-host

I am upgrading from a Mac OS X Server (running on an old Mac G3) to a new machine running "10.6.8 Server" and I was adding the Virtual Web Servers using the "Server Admin" app. As soon as I added the 121st Virtual Server, the Web Server stopped responding. I removed one of the other entries (to check if the last one had a problem) and the Web Server started again. After a lot of experiments I concluded that I could not have more than 120 Virtual Servers, no matter how or what those servers where.

Any ideas on how to overcome the 120 limit?
(on my G3, I had more than 200!)

Comment: 0_0. Why would someone need 120 virtual servers? Also, is there any errors? I'm not familiar with OSX but your web Server (apache?) should have some useful error messages somewhere.

Comment: In the Foundation I work (FHW in english IME in greek - 2 domains here) we are currently running more than 200 virtual servers on more than 60 domains (for example we have prehistory.fhw.gr, antiquity.fhw.gr, byzantium.fhw.gr, ottoman.fhw.gr, modern.fhw.gr for the 5 historical periods (of Greece) and the same with .ime.gr (pointing at the greek pages of the respective sites). That will make 10 virtual servers ONLY for the (main) site www.e-history.gr - Imagine that we have a museum that every exhibition has its own address/website, etc). Trust me, 120 is a small number...

Comment: No errors. It just stops working.

Comment: 10.6.8 is Snow Leopard, btw, not Yosemite.

Comment: Correct. Sorry. I edited it out. But the problem is the same. :)

Comment: If I was to leave the Mac OS X platform, Ubuntu would be a good choice. But I am not going to do that. (BTW, If I was to leave the Mac OS X platform, a easier step would have been to forget the graphic environment (Server Admin App) and then my problems would have been solved, since the Server Admin App is the problem here, not Apache ;-) )